# Retrieve select value from form without an ID

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit, hubspot

I'm trying to create a cookie to store a value from a select form field - I'v been trying different options but unsuccessful everytime  - can someone please help me?

The site is currently on Drupal but I'm wanting to add via Tag Manager, so any help with vanilla JS would be amazing

The Hubspot form in question can be located: https://www.huddle.com/get-started

The select field is : Comapany Size

The value I'm trying to target is the first option: 1-10

This is my code:

```
<script>



var formField = document.querySelector('form["name="size_of_organisation__c"]').value;

var formValue = "1-10";

var cookieName = sizeOfOrg;

var cookieValue = smb;



if (formField == formValue) {

 document.cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue";

}



</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Humm,
it seems you are using react, so it will be definitely nice to create this process in a react fonction inside your form component, etc.

I'm not really sure of your needs, but this code retrieve the value of the dropdown on change and add it in a cookie :

```html
<html>

<body>
    <form>
        <select name="size_of_organisation__c">
            <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Please Select</option>
            <option value="1-10">1-10</option>
            <option value="11-50">11-50</option>
            <option value="51-200">51-200</option>
            <option value="201-500">201-500</option>
            <option value="501-1000">501-1000</option>
            <option value="1001-5000">1001-5000</option>
            <option value="5001-10000">5001-10000</option>
            <option value="10001+">10001+</option>
        </select>

    </form>
</body>
<script src="./temp.js"></script>

</html>
```

```js
//selector to select dropdown. return an array so take the first one
var select = document.getElementsByName("size_of_organisation__c")[0];
console.log(select);

// add event handler to update the cookie each time you change the select
select.addEventListener("change", function() {
   document.cookie = "sizeOfOrg=" + select.value; 
   console.log(document.cookie);
});
```

*edit: add the html and the console.log() to debug*

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response - It's not React, it's a Drupal site so just wantiing to add via vanilla js - not sure what Hubspot is using tho... 

I've tried the code but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I edit to show a simplified html example based on your link.
if it doesn't work please share your html.

maybe your problem is the variable assignment:
```document.cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue";```
must be 
```document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue;```

Comment: thank you so much for your help so far. I've used your code snippet and the cookie is created, but the name = "" and the value = "sizeOfOrg" instead of the name = "sizeOfOrg" and the value = the select value eg. 1-10 or 11-50, etc